# How to find value of an unknown in matrix to make system of linear equations consistent

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I'm currently stuck on this question relating to finding the unknown in a matrix so that the system of linear equations is consistent. I need to solve for $\lambda$.

My first instinct is to try and reduce this into reduced row echelon form. Would this be the correct way to go about it and are there any other possible ways?

[image]

Comment: If you subtract the third row from the second row, you see that the resulting row of the matrix is identical to the first row of the matrix. Consistency would require that the resulting rhs vector element is the same as the first, i.e. $\lambda-5 = -3$, hence $\lambda = 2$.

Comment: Answering your direct question, yes echelon form row reduction would work as well.